# How do I use JavaScript to select content and move to other elements?

Tags: javascript

I need to move some text from `demoBoxA` to `demoBoxB`.

The `demoBoxA` parent element has an id selector, but the child element below it has no identifiable selector.

Is it possible to select the text content directly? Then move it into the `demoBoxB` sub-element (the `demoBoxB` sub-element has an id selector)

There are 2 difficulties with this issue.

1. The content of demoBoxA is dynamically generated by the program and the sort is not fixed. There are no identifiable selectors for the subelements.
2. only need to select part of the content. For example, in the example below, just move the phone model text of "Google", "Huawei", "BlackBerry".

Any help, thanks in advance!

```
<div class="container" id="demoBoxA">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Samsung</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Galaxy S10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Google</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Pixel 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Sony</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Xperia 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Huawei</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Mate 30 5G</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">BlackBerry</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">KEY2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Apple</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">iPhone 8</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="demoBoxB">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Google</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="pixel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Huawei</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="mate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">BlackBerry</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="key2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what you want to do is whenever you select a <div class="row"> element in demoBoxA you need to add entry over demoBoxB with same div elements by adding an id attribute to the second child element with the value of the model name but without the text content?

Comment: @ThilankaD Not so. I need to move some of the text content in the `demoBoxA` into the blank `div` of the `demoBoxA`, adding the id selector is to specify the target that needs to be moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain selectors like this:

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#demoBoxA > .row");
```

That will return a list of all rows inside of demoBoxA. If you need more info about chaining selectors, you can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Then, to move the rows you can do this:

```
var demoBoxB = document.getElementById('demoBoxB');

rows.forEach((row) => {
  demoBoxB.appendChild(row);
});
```

If you just want the text inside each of the columns, you can do this:

```
var columns = document.querySelectorAll("#demoBoxA > .col-md-6");
var texts = [];
columns.forEach((column) => {
  texts.push(column.innerText);
});
```

Now, `texts` is an array of the text contents of each column.

If you want to select the cellphone models for each brand, you can do this:

```
var cols = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#demoBoxA > .col-md-6"));
var samsungCol = cols.find((col) => {
  return col.textContent == "Samsung";
});

var samsungPhones = [];
samsungCol.parentNode.childNodes.forEach((col) => {
  if (col != samsungCol) {
    samsungPhones.push(col);
  }
});
```

Now, `samsungPhones` is a list of columns, one for each Samsung phone (for example).

Comment: This will select the entire content. Is it possible to select only the desired text content?

Comment: @Matthew I've updated my answer, please give it a try

Comment: Sorry, this is still not available. As described in the example. `demoBoxA` has 5 lines of text and it is dynamically generated by the program. there may actually be more lines and the order of arrangement is not fixed. I'm afraid I can't rely on the selector to select what's needed, is it feasible to select based on textual content?

Comment: So you want to select columns based on their text content? I've updated my answer, please check it out

Answer (score 0):

You can use html drag api .

Just add `draggable=true` for elements you want to drag and add event listeners for `dragstart` and `dragend`

html

```
<div class="container" id="demoBoxA">
    <div class="row " draggable="true">
        <div class="col-md-6">Samsung</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Galaxy S10</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" draggable="true">
        <div class="col-md-6">Google</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Pixel 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" draggabble="true">
        <div class="col-md-6">Sony</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Xperia 5</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="container " id="demoBoxB">
    <div class="row " draggable="true">
        <div class="col-md-6">Google</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="pixel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" draggable="true"> 
        <div class="col-md-6">Huawei</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="mate"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" draggable="true">
        <div class="col-md-6">BlackBerry</div>
        <div class="col-md-6" id="key2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
document.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e)
{
    item = e.target;
}, false);

document.addEventListener('dragend', function(e)
{
    document.getElementById("demoBoxB").appendChild(item)
}, false);
```

Note : you might have to add conditions to check whether the drop is actually happening in demoboxB

Comment: Sorry, this method does not solve my problem. Because the `demoBoxA` content is dynamically generated by the program, we cannot modify it to add the `draggable=true` property. Another difficulty is that `demoBoxA` content sorting is not fixed, making it difficult to use the selector to select the desired content.